# If $Q + R=\pi$ then verify that

Tags: trigonometry

If $Q + R =\pi $ then prove that $2(1-\sin Q\sin R.)=\cos^2 Q+ \cos^2 R$.

My attempt :

Here
, $Q+R=\pi$,
$Q=\pi - R$,
$\cos Q=\cos (\pi - R)$,
$\cos Q=-\cos R $,
$\cos^2 Q=\cos^2 R$.

Now,  what should I do to get this proved?

Comment: How about $\sin(Q)$ ?

Comment: @rdias,  sin^2 Q= sin^2 R

Comment: You have that $\sin(Q)=\sin(\pi - R)=\sin(R)$.

Comment: Hint: Draw a diagram. Then say ... Doh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $Q+R =\pi \Rightarrow R=\pi-Q\Rightarrow \sin R= \sin(\pi-Q) =\sin Q$.

Then our LHS becomes, $2(1-\sin Q\sin R) =2(1-(\sin Q)^2) =2(\cos Q)^2...(1)$.

We also know $\cos R= \cos(\pi-Q) = -\cos Q$.

Thus $(1)$ becomes $(\cos Q)^2 +(\cos Q)^2 = (\cos Q)^2 + (-\cos R)^2 = (\cos Q)^2 + (\cos R)^2 =\text{RHS}$. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin Q=\sin(\pi-R)=\sin R\implies 1-\sin Q\sin R=1-\sin^2R=\cos^2R$$

and now do something very simlar for cosine...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$$2(1-\sin Q\sin R.)=\cos^2 Q+ \cos^2 R$$
$$2(1-\sin Q\sin R.)=1-\sin^2 Q+ 1-\sin^2 R \Leftrightarrow (\sin R -\sin Q)^2=0 \Leftrightarrow \sin R =\sin Q$$

Comment: Hello Arnaldo Nascimento, sir

Comment: Hi, is the hint clear?

Comment: Yes, it is. Sir